# ActionBarSharlok not has the same behaviour on different resolutions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm developing an application and I have used ActionBarSharlok to be able to support Action Bar in earlier SDK versions

I have used android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to set Action Bar in the bottom of the screen.

it is working very well on Version 8 on Small Samsung Device
[image]

The problem happened when I test the application on Tablet Device of Version 15.

[image]

Now I'm facing a problem that I need the application to look the same on all devices. and to be in the bottom of the screen

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend having a split ActionBar on larger devices, because the split ActionBar is intended for small screens. But if you really need to, then override these boolean values in your `values-w480dp` folder:

```
<bool name="abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow">true</bool> // for ActionBarSherlock
<bool name="split_action_bar_is_narrow">true</bool> // for the default ActionBar
```

Comment: This does not work. I have tried this for App Compat.

Comment: If you create a user defined resource and add it to your project, it does not seem to override any library project. Are you talking about editing the source of ActionBarSherlock?